# part of the screen (Desktop) is black [Pic inside] (happens with 17.10s on Atom n270 laptops)

Tags: screen, monitor, 17.10, intel-atom

The mouse is visible on the black part, and i can drag windows from there.
Print screen produces a normal pic with all the desktop as it should look like.

I have this problem with 2 atom n270 laptops, With the first one I could "fix" it temproary by connecting an external screen, then switching to CLI (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and back to the gui (Ctrl+Alt+F7).
It might be a temporary fix for the second laptop too, just didn't check it.

It happens only in 17.10 versions (Ubuntu, Ubuntu mate, Lubuntu). Previous versions of Ubuntu are fine. Also Windows and Manjaro are fine.

Pic of second laptop having this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spPXm.jpg

[image]

Possible tags: screen, screen black, monitor, laptop, monitor and laptop, monitor display, 17.10, atom, atom n270, n270, intel atom,

Comment: This is a kernel bug 1724639 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1724639 . It was asked about on this site before but I can't find the question right now.  You will have to install an older kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'm the only one as I haven't managed to find any one talking about it. Good to know that it is already known.

Comment: My laptop is working now. I don't know how (One of them at least). I don't remember that I've done anything to it. I was using windows...

Comment: After a reboot... Same bug again ):

Comment: There is a fix listed at the bug report
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Simple editor 'nano' will open.
Add line
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
at the end of file.

Save file and exit from nano.

issue command:

sudo update-grub

reboot.

Comment: Same issue with Dell Mini 9, Intel Atom. 4.10 works, 4.13 fails. Testing with `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text` workaround. Working!

Answer (score 0):

Moving this to an answer.

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724639

**Symptom**

Upgrading Ubuntu to Linux 4.13 Kernel or higher that have an Intel based chipset may result in portions of the screen not being drawn properly (around 80%), leaving garbled or black portions that are not readable. Oddly, mouse cursor is drawn properly on all parts of the screen.

**Work Around**

Access the system via Command Line to make change (via root) to /etc/default/grub file.

If possible, connect via SSH. If not, hold down Left Shift key during boot to enter GRUB menu, select alternate kernel to load (in my case 4.10).

Run:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old
```

This creates a backup of your grub file.

Edit `grub` as root, I use `nano`.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for or add the following line:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

I also uncommented and updated the GFX Mode (will vary on your device):

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600,1024x600
```

Save changes and perform an update to grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can now reboot and the desktop should load with proper settings, being completely visible.

**GRUB Boot Commands**

If you cannot SSH, nor can you select an alternate kernel, there is another option. In the GRUB boot menu, press `e` to edit the commands. Add the following command to end of the command list:

```
set gfxpayload=text
```

Ubuntu should boot and you can then edit the grub file as instructed above.